# Gulp - error SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am trying to understand Gulp. I am on a Windows platform.

I have a simple `gulpfile.js` - but I keep getting

> SyntaxError. Unexpected token/identifier

I think it is saying identifier `gulp` is wrong but not sure. If it is, I'm not sure how I should set-up the `gulpfile` or what identifier to use

Sorry I can't post picture of log -- Here is gulpfile code

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var uglify      = require('gulp-uglify'); 

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    gulp.src('assets/js/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/js'));
});

gulp.task('styles', function () {

    gulp.src('assets/css/*.css')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/css'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'styles']
    gulp.src('assets/js/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/js'));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'styles'], function(){
    gulp.src('assets/js/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/js'));
});
```

add `function(){ /*logic*/ });` you missed this in default

Comment: Yes - I'm so new to gulp/javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks - Yes, I missed function() - now gulp gives a ReferenceError: uglyfly is not defined. Here is code again

```
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
    uglify      = require('gulp-uglify'); 
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src('assets/js/*.js')
    .pipe(uglyfly())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/js'))
});
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src('assets/css/*.css')
    .pipe(uglyfly())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/css'))
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'styles'], function () {

});
```